# Laravel Parent Child Relationship with Two Table

Tags: laravel, entity-relationship, eloquent-relationship

[Entity Diagram Of Two Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCV1y.png)

Parent Child Relationship Like this

1. TableA (id) is (parent_id) in TableA
2. TableB (id) is (parent_id) in TableB
3. TableA (id) is (parent_id) in TableB

   - Refer Entity Diagram Attached
   - Need Relationship to get all the childrens from two table of a given parent_id

Comment: If you have row in TableA how  how you can diferentiate which id it presents? TableA or TableB?

Comment: You need to apply normalization for your table first and then apply the Parent Child Relationship, you can not have internal relationship in side your tables

Comment: Just Parent-Child Entry In TableA and TableB. But Sometimes I will make an entry with TableA id as parent_id in TableB Record.

Comment: @AlirezaNazari how ?

Comment: Normalize your current schema by 1NF, 2NF and 3NF and then use Eloquent: Relationships. https://www.javatpoint.com/dbms-first-normal-form - https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships